# I use asp.net fileupload control to upload files but it is work on localhost not work on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use  asp.net fileupload control  to upload files  but  it is work on localhost  not work  on remote server  i use this   line of code to do this  but it is not work when i publish the page to server

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("products_images/") 
                               +  FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following.

1) The directory exists on the remote server. 
2) You have write permissions to the directory.

Also, do you get any exception? check your event logs on the server for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem with shared host [GoDaddy].
the problem comes from that you don't have the permission to access the files.
so please check the permission to write file in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter the absolute path of the remote directory.

I had this problem before, and solved by using an absolute path (e.g. \192.168.11.72\Images)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a hard coded path then it will be a file permission issue, you can access the cpanel of your hosting and give the iis user the permisssion to write files on the folder where you put your files.